# Problema para editar un elemento en una tabla con javascript y laravel

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando editar elementos en un `datatable` con `javascript`. La idea es no tener es actualizar los elementos en la misma tabla sin tener que cambiar de vista y sin tener que recargar. Pero uno de os campos que tengoq ue cambiar es un `select` con información que obtengo en la base de datos. Como puedo lograr poner el `select` en el código de mi función `transformarEnEditable`. A continuación dejo mi código `html` y `javascript`:

```
HTML

<form>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="center">Centro Laboral</th>
            <th class="center">Ocupaci&oacute;n</th>
            <th class="center">Direcci&oacute;n</th>
            <th class="center">--</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="cargo_actual">
            <tr id="actual">
                <td class="center" style="padding: 20px" id="lugar_trabajo">{{ $regMiembro->persona->lugar_trabajo }}</td>

                <td class="center" style="padding: 20px" id="ocupacion_laboral">{{ $regMiembro->persona->ocupacion_laboral }}</td>
                <td class="center" style="padding: 20px">
                    {{ $regMiembro->persona->DireccionTrabajo() }}
                </td>
                <td class="center" style="padding: 20px">
                        <span onclick="transformarEnEditable(this, {{ $regMiembro->persona->id }})" title="Editar Ocupaci&oacute;n Laboral" class='blue'>
                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil-square-o bigger-120"></i>
                        </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT. En esta funcion debe ponerse el campo select para seleccionar un elemento que obtengo desde la base de datos

```
function transformarEnEditable(nodo, id){

    id_venta = id;
    nodo_result = nodo;

    if (editando == false) {

        var nodoTd = nodo_result.parentNode; //Nodo TD

        var nodoTr = nodoTd.parentNode; //Nodo TR

        var nodosEnTr = nodoTr.getElementsByTagName('td');

        var lugar_trabajo = nodosEnTr[0].textContent;
        var ocupacion_laboral = nodosEnTr[1].textContent;
        direccion = nodosEnTr[2].textContent;

        var nuevoCodigoHtml =
            '<tr id="actual">'+
                '<td ><input type="text" name="numeracion" id="pagado_deuda" value="'+lugar_trabajo+'" size="15"></td>' +

                '<td class="align-center"><input type="text" class="form-group" name="pagado_producto" id="pagado_producto" value="'+ ocupacion_laboral +'" size="15"></td>' +

                '<td class="align-center">'+ direccion +'</td>' +

                '<td class="align-center"><a onclick="capturarEnvio(this)" class="green" title="Aceptar">' +
                '<i class="ace-icon fa fa-check bigger-120"></i></a> ' +
                '<a onclick="anular()" class="red" title="Cancelar"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-close bigger-120"></i></a></td>'+
            '</tr>';

        nodoTr.innerHTML = nuevoCodigoHtml;

        editando = "true";
    }
}
```

Después cuando salvo la información pongo la nueva información salvada en la misma tabla sin recargar; para esto uso una función llamada `capturarEnvio(nodo)`,

capturarEnvio():

```
function capturarEnvio(nodo){

    var datos = {
        lugar_trabajo: $('#pagado_deuda').val(),
        ocupacion_laboral: $('#pagado_producto').val(),
        id_venta: id_venta,
    };

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'{{ route('regMiembros.change_direccion') }}',
        data:{name: datos},

        success:function(data){


          $('#actual').remove();

            $('#cargo_actual').append('<tr id="actual"><td class="align-center">'+ datos.lugar_trabajo +' </td>' +
                '<td class="align-center">'+ datos.ocupacion_laboral +'</td>' +
                '<td class="center" style="padding: 20px">'+ direccion +'</td>' +
                '<td class="center" style="padding: 20px">' +
                '<span onclick="transformarEnEditable(this, data.idPersona)" title="Editar Ocupaci&oacute;n Laboral" class="blue">' +
                '<i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil-square-o bigger-120"></i></span></td>' +
                '</tr>');



        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: alguna idea familia ??

Comment: Te recomiendo Vuejs. Es una librería javascript con una curva de aprendizaje muy baja y con exelente integración con Laravel, que te permitirá crear aplicaciones SPA(Single Page Applications). Esto le puedes hacer por supuesto con jquery pero sería muy engorroso. Vuejs haría todo muy fácil, y esta orientado a solucionar este tipo de problemas. Aquí un ejemplo: https://vue-myena-table.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: Carga las opciones del select antes de editar y añadelas las a tu html cuando editas